# splash screen using android handler is not working

Tags: android, handler, splash-screen

my splash screen is not working.
it just flashes a empty layout for 2 seconds and loads the mainactivity...
i have added a png image from the drawable as the android:background for the splash screen.
but it does not displays the image..
i have also tried a textfield in the splash screen, but again it displays an empty layout..

this is my code for splash screen activity

public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    //Handler handler = new Handler();

    // run a thread after 2 seconds to start the home screen
    //handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // make sure we close the splash screen so the user won't come
            // back when it presses back key

            finish();
            // start the home screen

            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                    MainMenuActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);


        }

    }, 2000); // time in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds) until
                // the run() method will be called

}
```

}

Comment: uncomment setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

Comment: why did you comment setContentView out?

Comment: thank you for your reply sir..
but i have tried that too..

Comment: yeah its working... i just uncomment setcontentView().. thank you all.. scofcoder, blakbelt and Drakkin :)

Comment: Splash screens are an iOS thing, please don't use them in Android unless you have background operation that needs to run on each start of the app and is so blocking that it doesn't allow you to show any UI to the user until that operation finishes. Consider the UX side of things : for the user, each time the app is started, he/she has to wait for the splash screen to go away before he/she can actually use the app. That doesn't look good IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my splash screen code and it is working :

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 1500;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, DrawerActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

try with it